# Deduction in template functions with few args

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction, function-templates

I have few instances of one template function. Each of them sequentially executes each of given lambdas, accompanying them with specific messages. When I do that with one lambda, everything works fine, but when I try to add more than one, I get

```
note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Task'
```

From *clang*. Here is my code:

```
template <class Task> void doTasks(Task task1)  // works fine
{  
    if (std::__is_invocable<Task>::value) 
    {
        std::cout << "doing first task" << endl;
        task1;
    }
}

template <class Task>
void doTasks(Task task1, Task task2) // deduced conflicting types
{ 
    if (std::__is_invocable<Task>::value) 
    {
        std::cout << "doing first task" << endl;
        task1();
        std::cout << "doing second task" << endl;
        task2();
    }
}


int main()
{
    doTasks([&] (){std::cout << "1" << endl;}); 

    doTasks([&] (){std::cout << "1" << endl;},
            [&] (){std::cout << "2" << endl;}); 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

What's wrong with it? How can I deal with my problem?

Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm some kind of beginner in C++ and may not understand some template nuances.

Comment: Two different lambdas always have two different types, so the second template won't match. Try `template <class Task1, class Task2> void doTasks(Task1 task1, Task2 task2)` etc.

Comment: Who told you about `__is_invocable`? Any symbol beginning with double underscore should be considered private and an implementation-detail that should not be used by normal application code (unless specified and mentioned by the C++ specification, like e.g. the `__cplusplus` macro).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude compiler told me. In my real code there is just ```is_invocable```, but for some reason Clang couldn't compile example with this and suggested me to add ```__```. Anyway, thanks for explaining what does that mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though the two passed lambdas does the same or looks similar, they have completely different types. Hence, you need two different template types there in the `doTasks`.

Easy fix is providing the template parameter for two lambdas

```
template <class T1, class T2>
void doTasks(T1 task1, T2 task2)
{
  // ...
}
```

otherwise, using the variadic template function and [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), you could do something like:

```
#include <type_traits> // std::conjunction_v, std::is_invocable

template <class... Ts>
void doTasks(Ts&&... lmds) {
    if (std::conjunction_v<std::is_invocable<Ts>...>) // maybe if constexpr
    {
        (lmds(), ...);
    }
}
```

Since the argument is variadic, it will also work for the single/ any arguments of `doTasks` and hence no code duplication.

*[Live demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KcMK9f4fb)*

Comment: I read about fold expressions and it's very nice feature, but as you can see in my example, I need to print something between lambdas, but I can't find anything about putting few expressions there.

Comment: @sovesti May be, you pack the intermediate things as a callable object and call the `doTasks`  with them in an order. Here is an example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jvMxhnbM8

Answer (score 2):

The lambdas are of different types. You need to add another template parameter for the second one:

```cpp
#include <type_traits> // for the proper `std::invocable`

template <class Task, class AnotherTask>
void doTasks(Task task1, AnotherTask task2) {
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<Task> && std::is_invocable_v<AnotherTask>) {
        std::cout << "doing first task\n";
        task1();
        std::cout << "doing second task\n";
        task2();
    }
}
```

Note: Since it's C++17, you can also use [*constexpr if*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) to deal with the `if` at compile time only.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aqPG7bee5)